# Android - Facebook Custom Story image not displayed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got a custom story set up on my Facebook Developer for my app and I want to share a story with Android Facebook SDK. With the debug version of the app everything works fine, but when i sign it with my release key the preview just show me the website title ande the Facebook app image instead of the "object" title and image.
Here's my code:

OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);

```
        OpenGraphObject ogobj = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("item");
        ogobj.setProperty("title", fb_data.getTitle());
        ogobj.setProperty("image", obj.getPhotos().get(0));

        ogobj.setProperty("description", fb_data.getDesc());
        ogobj.setProperty("url", fb_data.getUrl());

        List<Bitmap> shareImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        shareImages.add(arg0);

        action.setType("myapp:share");
        action.setProperty("item", ogobj);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(Act_object.this, action, "item")
        .build();

        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

The action "share" has been approved by Facebook.
If I don't set the "url" property, the dialog (in signed apk) doesen't show and logcat gives me this:

```
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229): com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: [code] 100 [message]: (#100) conflicting og:type found in path (myapp:item) and 'properties' (item) [extra]: 
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.b(ApiResponseChecker.java:104)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:137)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:234)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseChecker.a(ApiResponseChecker.java:185)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.JsonResponseHandler.a(JsonResponseHandler.java:34)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.b(ApiResponseHandler.java:91)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.a(ApiResponseHandler.java:54)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiResponseHandler.handleResponse(ApiResponseHandler.java:29)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:738)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:214)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:167)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.common.FbHttpRequestProcessor.a(FbHttpRequestProcessor.java:323)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.a(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:550)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.SingleMethodRunnerImpl.b(SingleMethodRunnerImpl.java:257)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.http.protocol.AbstractSingleMethodRunner.a(AbstractSingleMethodRunner.java:20)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.platform.common.server.SimplePlatformOperation.a(SimplePlatformOperation.java:39)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.platform.common.server.PlatformOperationHandler.a(PlatformOperationHandler.java:59)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.e(BlueServiceQueue.java:376)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue.d(BlueServiceQueue.java:62)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.fbservice.service.BlueServiceQueue$3.run(BlueServiceQueue.java:293)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at com.facebook.common.executors.ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.run(ListenableScheduledFutureImpl.java:60)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-24 16:29:21.129: W/fb4a(:<default>):BlueServiceQueue(9229):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Can't really understand what I do wrong...
Thanks in advance

EDIT:
This is my new code and now I can put the image on my story

```
        OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);

        OpenGraphObject ogobj = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("myapp:item"); 

        ogobj.setTitle(fb_data.getTitle());
        ogobj.setProperty("name", fb_data.getTitle());
        ogobj.setImageUrls(Arrays.asList(obj.getPhotos().get(0)));
        ogobj.setUrl(fb_data.getUrl());
        ogobj.setProperty("user_generated", "true");

        List<Bitmap> shareImages = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
        shareImages.add(arg0);

        action.setType("myapp:share");          
        action.setProperty("name", fb_data.getTitle());
        action.setProperty("title", fb_data.getTitle());
        action.setProperty("image", obj.getPhotos().get(0));
        action.setProperty("item", ogobj);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(Act_object.this, action, "item")
        .build();

        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

This is what I see with the signed APK:
[image]

Instead it should be like this (this is what happens with the debug app)

[image]

Prova3 is the name fb_data.getTitle() and the image is obj.getPhotos().get(0)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
OpenGraphObject ogobj = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("myapp:item");
```

Otherwise your action is looking for an object of type "myapp:item" in the "item" property, but you're only giving it an object of type "item".

Comment: No, it doesen't work, it still can't display the title I tried to put

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you do see?

Comment: I updatem my question and added some images (modified for privacy)

Comment: I'm assuming that you added the release key hash to your app settings? Do you have any OG tags at the "url" you're using? Lastly, what happens if you remove the "url" property, and use createForPost("myapp:item")?

Comment: Yes I added my release key hash (in my app I have a Facebook login and it works fine on release and on debug).
When i remove the "url" on debug it still works (like in the second image), in release it shows off the Facebook Dialog only with the "shared and item" phrase, wihout the object image or title.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend you file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs. There, you can provide a full repro that our support engineers can try out, and also allows you to provide confidential information that you might not be comfortable sharing elsewhere.